# Can Acrobat's JS interface automate hyperlinking an existing, formatted listing of page numbers?

Tags: pdf, javascript, adobe-acrobat

I am unfamiliar with Acrobat's Javascript interface and would like to know if the following is even possible: am having no luck searching for existing examples. It's hard to believe no one else has had to do this, so I am hoping this is a search fail on my part.

I am looking for a way to examine the font styles of numbers in an existing PDF (these numbers all have a specific font / font size), then automatically hyperlink these numbers so they go to their corresponding PDF pages. I know I can do this manually with the Links tool; I have about 700 page numbers to hyperlink, thus the need for automation.

If that sounds like making an existing table of contents: that's exactly it, but there's more than one table (also a table of figures, illustrations, an index...)

*Due to a long list of restrictions*, I **cannot** re-export the full document from its original source with these already hyperlinked. I have to work with a final (heavily edited) PDF. I know that'd be the best solution but again, this is impossible for me.

Before I launch into hours of script creation, could someone confirm if Acrobat gives me the capacity to do this? From the Googling I've done it seems like I'm asking for too much.

Thanks in advance (if anyone has pointers I'd take those too).

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat JavaScript has (unfortunately) very little access to the base of the document. It can find "words" on a page (words are strings of text, Acrobat believes belonging together). You can read out the "word", and its bounding box coordinates.

You can guess the font size based on the bounding box height, but you can not read it out. Neither can you the font nor its attributes.

In Acrobat JavaScript, you would loop through the pages, and on every page loop through the words, get the word and the coordinates. Then you would analyze that information to figure out whether it suits your need. To make a link target, you would create a view with its zoom coordinates.

For the source (from where you want to jump to the target), you would create a Button field, and as action set it to go to the according view. Existing views are not affected.

The alternative would be a production plug-in. You'd have to decide whether learning the Acrobat SDK would be worth the effort, however.